# Performance considerations with `Promise.all` and a large amount of asynchronous operations

Tags: javascript, performance, promise, bluebird

When using [`Promise.all`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#all---promise) with asynchronous code (in case of synchronous code, there is nothing to worry about), you can suffer from severe performance (if not other kinds of) issues, when you want to send out a whole bunch (be it tens, hundreds, thousands or even millions) of requests, given the receiving end of your asynchronous operations (e.g. the local filesystem, an HTTP server, a database, etc etc.) does not gracefully handle that many parallel requests.

For that case, it would be perfect if we could tell `Promise.all` up to how many promises we want to have in-flight simultaneously. However, since A+ is supposed to be lean, adding these sorts of fancy features would certainly not make sense.

So what would be a better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, first of all - it's impossible to give a concurrency argument to `Promise.all` since promises represent *already started* operations so you cannot queue them or make the wait before executing.

What you want to perform with limited concurrency is *promise returning functions*. Lucky for you - bluebird ships with this feature (As of version 2.x) using `Promise.map`:

```
 Promise.map(largeArray, promiseReturningFunction, {concurrency: 16});
```

The concurrency parameter decides how many operations may happen at once - note that this is not a global value - but only for this chain. For example:

```
Promise.map([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], function(i){
    console.log("Shooting operation", i);
    return Promise.delay(1000);
}, {concurrency: 2});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gyy9uk9t/)

Note that execution order is not guaranteed.

Comment: Great! Thanks a bundle! What's not so great is the time I wasted on my own thingy-deal... But you live and learn!

Comment: @Domi when bluebird 3.0 comes (soon!) the docs get a lot better on a dedicated doc website. Sorry this was not obvious to find - feel free to edit the docs and make a pull request those are always welcome.

Comment: Why does `Promise.map` fail to guarantee execution order?

Comment: @Bergi it doesn't _fail_ to guarantee it, it is completely intentional. It's a performance consideration - namely, if you're doing `[1...100]` with concurrency 2 and you're done with 2 there is no reason not to start 3 and wait for `2`. Also - this issue from a year ago: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/167

Comment: But 3 should still be started after 2 is started? What I found unexpected is that the fiddle logged `1 2 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3`.

Comment: @Bergi yes, since order is not "somewhat guaranteed", order is not guaranteed at all - in practice you usually don't _care_ what order `.map` is executed (I never cared about it and I use it all the time) - conceptually it just needs to `.map`. By the way the timing you're seeing is just because `.shift` is slower than a `.pop` iirc or something silly like that :D

Comment: Sure, a mapping function must not depend on order. Still it would be nice if one could say "here's an array of values, do something async with them but at most X at the same time, and *start with the first values*". What I always forget is that Bluebird's `map` works on arrays of promises as well, not only on arrays of values. For such a "stream" it makes sense of course, as described in the issue you linked.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm sure, I was simply not looking for the right thing, using the wrong keywords. The entire concept of batching is actually not entirely necessary, and yet it was the main keyword I used in my search. Two other keywords come to mind: `flight` (or `in-flight`), `throttle` and now of course also `concurrency`, but not at the time. Searching and making docs searchable are both art forms of their own! :)

Comment: @Domi again - doc pull requests are gladly entertained in the repo :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Is there any reason why we can't have a sort of hybrid between `all` and `map`, which only takes a single array (instead of `map` which wants an array and a function), but each entry might be a promise, thenable or value?... I mean other than the obvious impact it would have on performance... I guess I just answered my own question, but would there be any other issues with that idea?

Comment: Promises are already started operations, I don't understand your question.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum What I am looking for is a function that only takes a single array (lke `all`), but also taking functions as part of that array (like in my answer). `map`'s disadvantage is that it wants the same function for each element in the input array. What if one wants different functions or one function bound to different context? What kind of disadvantage would there be to having `all` also accept `function`s, in addition to promises and values, and also support the `concurrency` argument? Anything other than complexity and performance overhead?

Comment: @Domi I see, bluebird doesn't have that sort of function in - but you can always use `.map` with dummy values or roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

Since I was not able to find a pre-existing library to take care of promise batching, I wrote a simple primitive myself. It is a class that wraps an array of `function`s to be executed, and partitions it into batches of given size. It will wait for each batch to finish before running the next. It is a rather naive implementation. A full-blown throttling mechanism would probably be desirable in some networking scenarios.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93z8L6sw/2).

Code:

```
/**
 * Executes any number of functions, one batch at a time.
 *
 * @see http://jsfiddle.net/93z8L6sw/2
 */
var Promise_allBatched = (function() {
    var Promise_allBatched = function(arr, batchSize) {
        if (arr.length == 0) return Promise.resolve([]);
        batchSize = batchSize || 10;

        var results = [];
        return _runBatch(arr, batchSize, results, 0)
        .return(results);        // return all results
    };

    function _runBatch(arr, batchSize, results, iFrom) {
        // run next batch
        var requests = [];
        var iTo = Math.min(arr.length, iFrom + batchSize);

        for (var i = iFrom; i < iTo; ++i) {
            var fn = arr[i];
            var request;
            if (fn instanceof Function) {
                request = fn();
            }
            else {
                request = fn;
            }
            requests.push(request);            // start promise
        }

        return Promise.all(requests)        // run batch
        .then(function(batchResults) {
            results.push.apply(results, batchResults);    // store all results in one array

            console.log('Finished batch: ' + results.length + '/' + arr.length);
        })
        .then(function() {
            if (iTo < arr.length) {
                // keep recursing
                return _runBatch(arr, batchSize, results, iTo);
            }
        });
    }

    return Promise_allBatched;
})();
```

Comment: This implementation is actually pretty nifty, especially how you avoided creating deferreds through the entire thing. Note that this runs things in batches so it's somewhat wasteful in that it will run N items and will not start a single other item until all N items have completed.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum That is exactly what I wanted to do though. Is `Promise.map` with the `concurreny` parameter set different from that?

Comment: Yes, it will make sure only `N` items run at once, but it'll start the `N+1`th item as soon as the first one completes - making it much faster in some cases.

Answer (score -2):

```
let arry=[1,2,4,........etc];//large number of array

 while (arry.length) {
    //I splice the arry 0,10...so you can change the limit as your //wish(note your server should be handle your limit
  Promise.all(arry.splice(0, 10).map(async (eachArryElement) => {
                   let res = await yourAsyncMethod(eachArryElement);
    }))
           
}

function yourAsyncMethod(data){
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 //your logic
 resolve('your output')
   })
}
```